# How to use org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDSL methods while building the TableRecord (List) in Jooq?

Tags: jooq

I've a `MyTableRecord` class. And I'm trying to build list of `MyTableRecord` which I use for batch upsert using `loadInto` method.
One of the field in the `MyTableRecord`  is of type `byte[]`.
I've to convert the String from DTO using `org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDSL.encrypt` to get `byte[]` but this method returns `Field<byte[]`
But `MyTableRecord` doesn't accept `Field` type.

How do I solve this problem?

I've tried like this but it is not working.

```
Record r = dslContext.newRecord(MYTABLE.fields());
r.set((Field) MYTABLE.SECURESTRING, MySQLDSL.aesEncrypt(dataDTO.getSecureString(), String.valueOf(dataDTO.getKey())).cast(byte[].class));

dslContext.insertInto(MYTABLE).set(r)
```

But this is saving as `cast(aes_encrypt('secureString', '9757') as binary)` in the column

**Inserting a single record is not an issue, but I need to batchUpsert from list of DTO.**

Answer (score 0):

A jOOQ `Record` is similar to a `Map<Field<?>, ?>` where the key is a `Field<T>` and the value is a `T` value, i.e. a bind value. It can't have any expressions as values, just like a database record can't really have expressions as values.

What you want to do is just write an actual `INSERT` statement, namely:

```java
ctx.insertInto(MYTABLE)
   .set(MYTABLE.SECURESTRING, MySQLDSL.aesEncrypt(...))
   .execute();
```

You don't need the `Record` abstraction for your `INSERT` statement.